# Eclipse Run not asking how to run as, and opens wrong file

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I'm brand new to learning Python and am using Eclipse to go through a Python course. When I first started doing exercises in Eclipse, every time I opened a file from the course examples, the first time I ran it I would click the green "run" button, and it would ask me how I wanted to launch the file (as Python Run or Python Unit Test). Somewhere along the way it stopped doing that and now if I open a file that has never been run before, when I click the green run button, it just runs a different file. I can click through the drop down menus to run as and select python module and then the run button works fine any time I use that file, but I can't figure out why it won't just run new files the way that it did when I first installed eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have configured to run the last file... (PyDev asks if you want to do that in a dialog and does that for you if you confirm). Still, don't worry, this is probably for the best anyways as you can just hit **F9** to run your file directly without clicking anything (and **Ctrl+F11** or clicking the run should now re-run the last launch you did).

Make sure you take some minutes to read http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_run.html for tips on the best way to run Python modules from PyDev.

Comment: For what it's worth I'm using a Mac so the keyboard shortcuts are a bit different. I was able to figure that out, but I still can't figure out why Eclipse needs me to manually select a configuration out of the menu each time I run a python module that hasn't been run before. Changing the settings haven't seemed to make a difference for me.

Comment: You mean that using F9 is showing you a dialog? Can you post a screenshot of that?

Comment: I just got to the bottom of this. Eclipse has a keybinding to F9, but on my Macbook pro, when I hit F9, OSX goes into one of its animations that reveals all the windows open on my desktop. I thought that this meant the command would be mapped to something slightly different and perhaps I needed to dig more to find it, but I found that remapping the 'Run Editor with current interpreter' command to respond to ^F9 instead let me access that run command and gave me the result I wanted. Thanks @Fabio for your support, your help is so encouraging to a new coder like me!

Comment: Great that you've been able to sort it out ;)